# Snip and sketch default file format

Tags: windows-10, screenshot, snipping-tool

The "Snip and Sketch" tool in Windows 10 seems to default to saving as JPG whereas the "Snipping Tool" it replaces used (for me at least) to default to PNG, which is often a better choice for screenshots.

Snip and Sketch does remember my preferred directory for saving snips, but is there a way to remember my preferred file type?

Comment: Isn't PNG the [default option](https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-releases-a-new-update-for-snip-sketch-app-for-windows-10/)?

Comment: @CaldeiraG Nice find! Seems like they have changed this in response to feedback - that page is from Mar 19 and states that in the newly released version "We’ve updated the default save format to be png. You can still use the dropdown when saving to pick your desired format if it’s not png." My question was from Feb 19 so before the update unfortunately!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used Snip & Sketch for the first time ever, and it happily offered to
save in `png` format. So it seems that the
[default is still PNG](https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-releases-a-new-update-for-snip-sketch-app-for-windows-10/),
only that something has gone wrong on your computer.

I suggest to reinstall this Microsoft Store application using the following
PowerShell command:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.ScreenSketch | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

---

It seems like the above operation fixed the issue, but only for one use,
reverting to JPG on the second use. We must therefore do something more
drastic. Create a System Restore point before starting, just in case.

- Remove Snip & Sketch from Windows by the following command:

  ```
  Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.ScreenSketch | Remove-AppxPackage
  ```

  The above command uninstalls it from the current user account only.
  It might be preferable to uninstall it from all user accounts with the
  following command:

  ```
  Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.ScreenSketch | Remove-AppxPackage
  ```
- Search the disk for folders or files that contain the string
  "Microsoft.ScreenSketch" and delete them (very carefully).
  Do not take ownership of any Windows folders.
  One such folder is perhaps
  `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe`.
- Enter the Microsoft Store, search for `Snip & Sketch` and install it.

Comment: "only that something has gone wrong on your computer" - don't think it's this, it seems from that link that MS updated Snip and Sketch in March 2019 (a month after the question was asked) to change the file default to png as of version v10.1901.10521.0, presumably because other people were as annoyed as I was about the default being jpg!

Comment: Since I never used this product, it's evident that the default is PNG in Windows 10 version 1909. The something that has gone wrong on your computer can be the fault of the version 1909 installation, that hasn't undone the previous setting on the computer. This is why I think/hope that a reinstall will re-establish the right setting.

Comment: Thanks for this, after following your advice I now have v10.1907.2471.0 and it does indeed default to PNG the very first time you make a snip, which is the first time I've seen it do this! Saved it as a PNG, all is good. *Then the second time I made a snip, the default had switched back to JPG* :-(

Comment: I think we are getting closer, so I added a stronger method. Create a System Restore point before starting, just in case.

Comment: Default now seems to stick at PNG so I think this is solved now, many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to reset Snip & Sketch in Windows 10 is to go into:
Settings > Apps > Apps & features > search for Snip & Sketch > Advanced options > then just hit the reset button and try the app again.

Answer (score 1):

Just choose the desired format in the Save As dialog using the "Save as type" drop-down once when saving the image.  The choice will persist.
[image: Click Save, Save As... png, Save]

Comment: Thanks, just tried and this does now seem to be persistent after closing and restarting Snip and Sketch, so this should help anyone else with an issue  like mine - at the time I asked my question it wasn't persistent (extraordinarily!)